# Google Play Developer API: upload apk to production track but don't publish

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm using the python api to upload apks, mapping files and release note texts.

See https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/python/latest/androidpublisher_v2.edits.html

I'm using the `apks().upload()`, `deobfuscationfiles().upload()` and `apklistings().update()` APIs to upload the new apks, mapping files and changelogs, respectively.

Then I call `tracks().update()` to assign the uploaded apks to the *production* track.

Finally I call `commit()` to finalize the edit.

This, however, **immediately** publishes the new apks.

What I want is for the release manager to have the final confirmation on the new release. So there should be a manual review/publish step like in a manual release.

Is this possible using the API. Do I use the wrong API calls?

One way of course would be to upload on the beta/alpha track and then have the release manager move it to production. But is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the new version of Google Play Developer API v3, where you can now set "status" (completed, draft, stopped, inProgress) for Edits.tracks.

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v3/python/latest/androidpublisher_v3.edits.tracks.html

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to have a manual review step at the moment.